Is the minimum of the modulus of a parametric function convex or concave?
I have a function that looks like this
min_{r \in R, l \in L} |l-r|
Is this function convex or concave? I’ve read somewhere that |x| and that the minimum of convex functions is also convex. But I have also seen sources that say that the minimum function is concave.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

$\min\limits_{r\in\Bbb R, l\in L}\lvert l-r\rvert$ is a constant (and it's $0$). The function $x\mapsto\min{\lvert x\rvert, \lvert x-1\rvert}$ is neither convex nor concave.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In general, is the min |x| convex or concave?

$\min \lvert x\rvert=0$.

So min |x| which is a constant is both convex and concave? Under what assumption will it be only convex?

I've already told you that $\min\limits_{r\in\Bbb R,l\in L}\lvert l-r\rvert=0$.

You've stated that you intend "$\min_{r\in R, l\in L} |l-r|$" to be a function.  What are you thinking would be the input to this function?  Or are you intending that $r$ and $l$ are themselves functions (i.e. $r(z)$ and $l(z)$, and the minimum is taken pointwise over all the possible $z$'s)?
